# Angular lifecycle, data fetched after ngOnInit

Tags: angular, lifecycle

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    const currentToken = localStorage.getItem('xoAuthToken');
      if (currentToken) {
        const data = { token: currentToken };
        this.userService.verifyToken(data)
          .subscribe((response: any) => {
            if (response.result && response.user) {
              this.authService.authenticate(response.user);
            }
          });
      }
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
public authenticated = new Subject();

public authenticate(user) {
  this.user = user;
  this.authenticated.next(this.user);
}

public getUser() {
  return this.user;
}
```

The problem is, when I try to get user information in another component from AuthService like this:

some.component.ts:

```
public ngOnInit() {
  const user = this.authService.getUser();
  console.log(user);
}
```

It's not initialized yet, so where should I check localStorage for a token and make a http request, so that in any component at OnInit, the data is already available?

Comment: I added some more code to make it a bit clearer, I'm not good at explaining this with words in english @bugs

Answer (score 0):

use the behavior subject for that

```js
public authenticated = new BehaviorSubject(null);

public authenticate(user) {
  // Auth function : return undefined if the user failed to login.
  this.authenticated.next(this.user);
}
```

In your components :

```js
public ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.authenticated.subscribe(user => {
    if (user === null) { /* not logged yet */ }
    else if (user === undefined) { /* failed to log in */ }
    else if (!!user) { /* is logged */ }
  });
}
```

This subscription will be triggered everytime you call `next` on your BSubject.

Comment: This is what I've been doing in my components so far, but what if I need to access this data in an auth guard on canActivate or some custom directive?

Comment: You can return an observable or a promise for guards, and you can simply subscribe to this subject in your directives.